# Numbered voting

Tags: voting

I would be so very grateful if someone could help me out! I have been searching the internet for ages now looking for a way to achieve the desired user interactivity mentioned below (perhaps there is a similar script available already that I don't know of?).

The problem:

Supporting image: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v291/Dark_Jessa/btn_instructions.jpg

There is a list of candidates, each with a circle next to them. When a user clicks inside a circle, a number will appear inside. This process will continue for all other circles, with numbers appearing in ascending order.

If a user changes their mind on the number they have given a circle, the user can click on the number and it will go away from the circle.

When the user clicks inside another circle, the number inside the circle will be replaced by the number that was being held by the cursor.

EXAMPLE:
The user wants “David MORGAN” to be their second choice. So the user will click inside the circle next to “David MORGAN”. The number ‘3’, which was previously in the circle, is now removed form the circle.

The user now clicks on the circle next to “Steve PRATT”, which has the number ‘2’ inside. The number ‘3’ which was attached to the user cursor has now replaced the number 2 upon click. The user is now invisibly holding onto the number ‘3’.

The next part I would like is for there to be a submit button. When the user presses the button, their circle choices will be displayed on the new page, so they can confirm the selection.

If they press the submit button, and all circles have not been entered, they will be taken to a page informing them of this.

I don't need any of the data recorded permanently, just the choices recorded temporary on the confirmation.

Any ideas? :3

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mention a language.

Comment: @user: yes, I agree with @Ignacio. How about some context? Your tags are really meaningless.

Comment: What do you need help with? We can't help you do the whole thing, but we can provide guidance on small parts of the problem.

Comment: Sorry :( I guess PHP, or javascript would be the easiest for me to use. That's if this can be achieved using either of them.

Comment: What is the nature of the project?

Comment: My main problem is the user interface: clicking on a circle and having a number appear. Then if you click on another circle, the ascending number will appear.

Comment: It's a graphic design school project, creating a mock-up of an online voting system for a State election. I don't -need- to make it interactive. But I would really like to if there are similar scripts available to help make this mock-up work. :)

Comment: JS would be the better language, since it won't require a page reload an round trip to the server. On the topic of homework, please read the [SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) ["How to ask and answer homework questions?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rank should be unassigned, assigned to a candidate, or held "by the mouse" for assignment. Code something that puts each rank in one of these three states.

For example, use two (non-global) variables, (e.g.) `nextRank` and `nowRank`. The value of nextRank means all ranks >= nextRank are unassigned.

When the user clicks on an empty circle:

1. if nowRank is a positive integer, assign the candidate the rank nowRank and set nowRank to 0
2. else assign the candidate nextRank and increment nextRank

When the user clicks on a filled circle,

1. if nowRank is a positive integer, swap the candidate's rank and nowRank (if non-zero)
2. else set nowRank to the candidate's rank and clear the candidate's rank.

Since this is a homework questions, here's another scenario for you to consider: clicking a ranked candidate unassigns that rank, but won't assign a previously unassigned rank. Ranks are only assigned when a candidate has no rank. How would you implement this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though I am very much a n00b when it comes to programming! But yeah...now I think about it, its getting a bit complicated. I think I had probably better brainstorm a better way... :S

Comment: The above isn't too complicated. It could be done with nested `if` statements, two levels deep (the outer testing whether or not a candidate has been ranked, the inner testing whether or not nowRank is positive). With JS, the code would be in a function that you'd register as a click handler for the candidates' list elements. There are other, perhaps slicker ways, but nested `if`s should suffice.